# nav buttons on owl carousel affecting other sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have here two owl carousel with a custom nav, working when only one carousel but when I add multiple carousels, all carousels function the same and not indepedently

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yvfokwz8/)

Here is my JS code

```
jQuery(function(){
var owl = jQuery('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    autoplay: 2000,
    items:1,
    nav:false,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:5000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true, 
    loop: true,
    dots: false,
    onInitialized  : counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
    onTranslated : counter //When the translation of the stage has finished.
});
jQuery('.customNextBtn').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})
// Go to the previous item
jQuery('.customPrevBtn').click(function() {
    // With optional speed parameter
    // Parameters has to be in square bracket '[]'
    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
})
function counter(event) {
   var element   = event.target;         // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
    var items     = event.item.count;     // Number of items
    var item      = event.item.index + 1;     // Position of the current item

  // it loop is true then reset counter from 1
  if(item > items) {
    item = item - items
  }
  jQuery(element).parent().find('.counter').html(item + " / " + items);
}
});
```

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yvfokwz8/) again

All I need to make them work independently. they are working when dragging images but when you use the arrows then it just move all of the sliders

I think it has something to do with the button clicks, it does not find its parent div, i guess

Comment: add ID on main div of owl carosel like :

var owl = jQuery('#owl-carouselone');
var owltwo = jQuery('.owl-carouseltwo');

Comment: I don't think that can be done since every slider is dynamic using ACF, so there might be more than two, there might be 10 more

Comment: you'll have to use different carousal initializers for evey carousal . Check here https://jsfiddle.net/97j9gmtm/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize each owl separately. For if you can use `each` from jQuery. For example for your case:

```
jQuery(function(){
var owlContainers = jQuery('.container');

owlContainers.each(function(index, owlItem) {
  var $owlContainer = jQuery(owlItem);
  var $owl = $owlContainer.find('.owl-carousel');
  $owl.owlCarousel({
    autoplay: 2000,
    items:1,
    nav:false,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:5000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true, 
    loop: true,
    dots: false,
    onInitialized  : counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
    onTranslated : counter //When the translation of the stage has finished.
  });
  $owlContainer.find('.customNextBtn').click(function() {
    $owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
  })
  // Go to the previous item
  $owlContainer.find('.customPrevBtn').click(function() {
    // With optional speed parameter
    // Parameters has to be in square bracket '[]'
    $owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
  })
})

function counter(event) {
   var element   = event.target;         // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
    var items     = event.item.count;     // Number of items
    var item      = event.item.index + 1;     // Position of the current item

  // it loop is true then reset counter from 1
  if(item > items) {
    item = item - items
  }
  jQuery(element).parent().find('.counter').html(item + " / " + items);
}
});
```

It's working good because we use different prev and next button for each carousel.

P.S. Please change class '.container' to '.owl-wrapper' it's necessary because we should divide css styles and JS logic

P.S.S It will be working for 'N' carousel on the page

Answer (score 0):

for the appropriate solution::

```
    jQuery(function(){
    var owl1 = jQuery('#owl-carousel1');
    var owl2 = jQuery('#owl-carousel2');
    owl1.owlCarousel({
        autoplay: 2000,
        items:1,
        nav:false,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:5000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true, 
        loop: true,
        dots: false,
        onInitialized  : counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
        onTranslated : counter //When the translation of the stage has finished.
    });

owl2.owlCarousel({
        autoplay: 2000,
        items:1,
        nav:false,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:5000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true, 
        loop: true,
        dots: false,
        onInitialized  : counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
        onTranslated : counter //When the translation of the stage has finished.
    });
    jQuery('.customNextBtn').click(function() {
        owl1.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    })
    // Go to the previous item
    jQuery('.customPrevBtn').click(function() {
        // With optional speed parameter
        // Parameters has to be in square bracket '[]'
        owl1.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
    })
    function counter(event) {
       var element   = event.target;         // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
        var items     = event.item.count;     // Number of items
        var item      = event.item.index + 1;     // Position of the current item

      // it loop is true then reset counter from 1
      if(item > items) {
        item = item - items
      }
      jQuery(element).parent().find('.counter').html(item + " / " + items);
    }
    });
```

add ids on both carousels.

Comment: Hi, the slider is dynamic, adding an ID wont help since it maybe more and its dynamically added using the flexible content in ACF

Comment: you can add id using loops, try once, i think it i helpful.